# zip direct link download not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-7, zip, download

Zip file direct link download not working in IE7 and IE8

Examlple: http://beta-ffconeworld.fairfactories.org/Uploads/documents/docfiles/122_test.zip

```
$ curl -I http://beta-ffconeworld.fairfactories.org/Uploads/documents/docfiles/122_test.zip
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2011 10:58:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Amazon)
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Jul 2011 10:09:11 GMT
ETag: "7cc4-8565-4a818d74be4db"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 34149
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/zip
```

Comment: Is this a file sitting on the server or is it something you are generating each time the URL is hit?

Comment: Is it not working in some particular fashion?

Comment: we upload zip files to server through file upload when we try to download it we are using direct url but files are not downloading properly in IE but mozilla does correct

Comment: *How* does the download fail? Is it displayed within the browser, are you getting an error message by the server? Are you getting an error message by the browser? Is the file downloaded and saved on disk but you can not open it? Please be more precise about the error.

Comment: What web server is being used?  (Apache, IE?)

Comment: that's the server signature: `Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Amazon)`.

Comment: @praneeth, I'll try to rephrase my question: how exactly do you notice that *are not downloading properly*? What can you see in your computer screen that makes you exclaim: "Hey, it's not properly downloaded!"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue once and solved it by disabling gzip compression in apache for the particular file extension or directory.

In my case apache was trying to compress a file that was already compressed thus corrupting it.  We added

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary
```

into httpd/conf/extra/httpd-deflate.conf and all was well.

Comment: Applying HTTP compression on a ZIP file is of course pointless but it should not corrupt it :-?

Comment: It was my understanding the http compression was applied to every file regardless - in our case we were getting corrupt zip files in IE as well and as soon as well stopped gzip on .zip file that problem went away.

Answer (score 1):

[image: IE7 Security settings]

Works fine on my machine.

Check your security settings.  In IE7, this is Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Custom Level... in the list it's possible to disable file downloads, or enable them to download without prompt.